# Откуда произошло слово вага?

Tags: этимология

Помимо этого слова есть: розга, слега, батога, Лага, и все со значением палки.
А еще куча гидронимов с таким окончанием на ГА.

Answer (score 1):

http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Vaga-148.html -- адрес словаря. Того вместо, чтобы ждать ответа от снисходительности к лени, открой словарь!

Comment: Оттого и не открываю, что  надоело, куда не ткни, одни немцы нас говорить учили, это с каких таких пор, если немецкого как такового то и не было аж до  Бисмарка?

Comment: Но сынок мой рускавай, не изволишь ли ты, благодушнай, согласиццца, что грамотный немец лучше учитель, чем бззззгряматьнай ты.  
"Оттого и не открываю, что надоело, куда не ткни..." Умнай мой, когда ткнюешь, не поворачивайся к себе задом.
Филолог высшего класса, еврей, гражд. США, переводчик правит. США.  
Нельзя на тебя Его Величество Язык Русский оставлять. Уж больно ценная вещь. 

Дай мне адрес. Пришлю еврейские чернила, сделанные в США перегонкой русского словаря нерусского Даля.

Comment: Открыл словарь... *"...Заимств. из д.-в.-н. wâga, нов.-в.-н. Wage "весы"..."* Не убеждает. Весы - "механистическое" понятие, возникшее значительно позже, чем понятие "тяжесть", "вес", "ответственность" и т.п. Так-что тут, скорее, обратное заимствование.

*"...Голуб видит ... корень .. везу́ .. что сомнительно в фонетическом отношении."* Сомнения в данном вопросе не делают чести Фасмеру. Замещение "g"="з" у булгар, как и замещение "g"="г"/"ж" у сколотов, имеет массу примеров.

Comment: вага всегда была палкой, отважить--побить палкой, с везу никакой связи по-любому.

Comment: "Вага" в большинстве славянских языков - "вес, тяжесть". У нас - словом "вага" обычно именуют **рычаг**, используемый при подъёме или перемещении тяжёлых грузов

Comment: ну так, сначала палка, а потом из палки рычаг, а уж потом и весы.

Comment: Вот тут Вы не правы. Сперва **вес**. Именно в этом значении слово получило наибольшее распространение. А, уж, потом - все производные.

Полагаю, что скифы использовали "wag" для обозначения как повозки, так и её груза.

 У булгар "wag" превратился в "waz". не потеряв, при этом значения.

Германцы сохранили "wag" как основу для "waggen" (повозка). А, вот, значение "груз" - утратили.

Ну, и, наконец, сколоты сперва "редуцировали" "wag" в значении "вес" в "вага".

Русским "вага" досталась от сколотов, а "вес" и "воз" - от булгар.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё есть луга, стога и ряд других существительных м.р. мн.ч., имеющих такое же окончание. А если вспомнить существительные женского рода....

Не ищите чёрную кошку в тёмной комнате. Её там нет.

Comment: луг и стог, а вы дорогой, путаете  по жизни множественное с отдельным, счетным.
а еще по вашему принципу можно и друга прицепить, под(п)руга, и прочее, чего душенька ваша пожелает, гирька, она золотая, если Паниковский скажет.

Comment: Разве не Вы привели в качестве примера "батога"?
Ед.ч. - "батог" (посох, толстая палка, палка используемая для наказания)

Comment: батоги,  я тоже ошибся.

Comment: Жаргонное "батога" используется. Наряду с "паруса", "шторма" и т.п. Приведённые мной "луга" и "стога" из того же ряда (когда-то были жаргонными).

Comment: да какое уж жаргонно, когда множественное число? Причем еще спорно, шторма или штормы, луги или луга.

Comment: "Шторма", "ветра" и "паруса" - давно устоявшаяся форма мн.ч. от "шторм" (вместо "штормы"), "ветер" (вместо "ветры") и "парус" (лексически правильное "парусы" не используется). Все три примера заимствованы из морского **жаргона**.
Аналогичным способом образованы жаргонизмы "профессорА", "шоферА" и т.п.. В литературном языке считаются недопустимыми.
Очевидно, что "лугА" и "стогА" - слова из того же ряда.. Но "правильная" форма этих слов ("луги" и "стоги") давно не используется.

Comment: cсогласен.

Answer (score 0):

Из санскрита: vAha - переносчик тяжестей, vAhya - повозка или животное с поклажей, laghu - легкий, lagati - прилагать, lagna - прикрепленный, laguDa - палка (лом). Попутно: avadhi - внимание (т. е. уважение может быть и не от веса происходит).